# Read .raw file in matlab?

Tags: matlab, fopen, raw

I have data from https://coastalmonitoring.org/realtimedata/index.php?chart=97&tab=1Hz%20Data&disp_option=2 in formate .raw. How do I read this file in matlab?

It is sequential data, 1 dimentional data.

I have trid to use fopen, but the numbers I get seems to be weird.

```
% Open the raw file
fid = fopen('BidefordBay}2024-01-25T12h00Z.raw', 'r');
data = fread(fid, [1000, 50], 'double');

% Close the file
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: The file format is described in a document accessible from your link: [Datawell File Formats](https://coastalmonitoring.org/realtimedata/datawell_technicalnote_fileformats_2013-03-14.pdf). As a side note, it seems their `.raw` files are actually in ascii format. Have you tried opening the `.raw` file in a text editor ?

Answer (score 1):

A `.raw` dataset is as its name suggests, raw, uncooked. No change done to the bytes.

This means that there is no unique way to read `.raw` datasets, and that you just need to know how to "cook" it, you need to know if its double or other data type, the size, the length, if it contains a header, if its endianness, if it has compression, encryption etc.

Can you do it in MATLAB? yes of course. But each `.raw` file will need a separate function, and we can't really help you figure out what your `.raw` looks like.